# SwiftUI: Center Content in ScrollView

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to center a bunch of views in a `VStack` within a `ScrollView` in SwiftUI. To simplify things, I'm just trying to get it to work with a single `Text` view. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
var body: some View {
  ScrollView(alwaysBounceVertical: true){
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
      Spacer()
      Text("This Is a Test")
      Spacer()
    } //HStack
    .background(Color.green)
  } //ScrollView
  .background(Color.gray)
}
```

This results in this:

[image]

I want the text to be in the middle like this:

[image]

So the `HStack` should be full-width and the `Text` should be centered within it. It seems like this should be easy, but I don't get what I'm doing wrong. :)

Comment: I'm using Xcode beta 5 and your code is working fine with me. Which Xcode are you using ? Because In beta 5, ScrollView doesn't have **alwaysBounceVertical** Modifier.

Answer (score 21):

Using GeometryReader, you can get information about the size of the containing view and use that to size your view.

```
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in                <--- Added
            ScrollView(alwaysBounceVertical: true){
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("This Is a Test")
                    Spacer()
                } //HStack
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)  <--- Added
                .background(Color.green)
            } //ScrollView
        .background(Color.gray)
    }
}
```

edit: after looking into this more, it seems that part of the problem is that you are using a ScrollView. If you remove that parent, the spacers in the HStack will automatically cause stretching to fill the view. I'm guessing the automatic stretching doesn't happen in ScrollViews because there's no finite limit to how big it can be, how much would it stretch? (because a ScrollView can scroll in any direction)

Comment: This sounds like a good explanation. But should it not be possible maybe to limit one scrolling direction for a scrollview to fix such issues? 

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a bug in Xcode 11.0 beta, `ScrollView` content wouldn't fill the scroll view. If you replace the `ScrollView` with a `List` it will work as expected. But if you have to use a scroll view, one workaround is to fix the scroll view's content **width**.

So your code will look something like this:

```
ScrollView(alwaysBounceVertical: true) {
  HStack(alignment: .center) {
    Spacer()
    Text("This Is a Test")
    Spacer()
  } // HStack
  .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width) // set a fixed width
  .background(Color.green)
} // ScrollView
.background(Color.gray)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Please use `GeometryReader` rather the `UIScreen` bounds

Comment: @MatteoPacini Why is that? Is it because it won't work when the device is rotated?

Comment: This solution works, but now I'm just debating between setting the `.frame` and using `GeometryReady`. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You should use the modifier `frame` and set its `maxWidth: .infinity`.
So it tells its parent: "the wider, the better" :)

```
var body: some View {
  ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true){
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
      Spacer()
      Text("This Is a Test")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // <- this
      Spacer()
    } //HStack
    .background(Color.green)
  } //ScrollView
  .background(Color.gray)
}
```

And this works regardless its parent.
Scrollview or whatever View it's set in.

Paul is doing a great job clarifying it to all of us here:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-give-a-view-a-custom-frame

Answer compatible with Xcode 12.1 (12A7403)
I hope this helps 
dsa

Comment: There isn't constructor method with alwaysBounceVertical for ScrollView.

Comment: @ErkamKUCET fixed